# Quickly remove zero variance variables from a data.frame

Tags: r, data-management

I have a large data.frame that was generated by a process outside my control, which may or may not contain variables with zero variance (i.e. all the observations are the same).  I would like to build a predictive model based on this data, and obviously these variables are of no use.

Here's the function I'm currently using to remove such variables from the data.frame.  It's currently based on `apply`, and I was wondering if there are any obvious ways to speed this function up, so that it works quickly on very large datasets, with a large number (400 or 500) of variables?

```
set.seed(1)
dat <- data.frame(
    A=factor(rep("X",10),levels=c('X','Y')),
    B=round(runif(10)*10),
    C=rep(10,10),
    D=c(rep(10,9),1),
    E=factor(rep("A",10)),
    F=factor(rep(c("I","J"),5)),
    G=c(rep(10,9),NA)
)
zeroVar <- function(data, useNA = 'ifany') {
    out <- apply(data, 2, function(x) {length(table(x, useNA = useNA))})
    which(out==1)
}
```

And here's the result of the process:

```
> dat
   A B  C  D E F  G
1  X 3 10 10 A I 10
2  X 4 10 10 A J 10
3  X 6 10 10 A I 10
4  X 9 10 10 A J 10
5  X 2 10 10 A I 10
6  X 9 10 10 A J 10
7  X 9 10 10 A I 10
8  X 7 10 10 A J 10
9  X 6 10 10 A I 10
10 X 1 10  1 A J NA

> dat[,-zeroVar(dat)]
   B  D F  G
1  3 10 I 10
2  4 10 J 10
3  6 10 I 10
4  9 10 J 10
5  2 10 I 10
6  9 10 J 10
7  9 10 I 10
8  7 10 J 10
9  6 10 I 10
10 1  1 J NA

> dat[,-zeroVar(dat, useNA = 'no')]
   B  D F
1  3 10 I
2  4 10 J
3  6 10 I
4  9 10 J
5  2 10 I
6  9 10 J
7  9 10 I
8  7 10 J
9  6 10 I
10 1  1 J
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Don't use `table()` - very slow for such things. One option is `length(unique(x))`:

```
foo <- function(dat) {
    out <- lapply(dat, function(x) length(unique(x)))
    want <- which(!out > 1)
    unlist(want)
}

system.time(replicate(1000, zeroVar(dat)))
system.time(replicate(1000, foo(dat)))
```

Which is an order magnitude faster than yours on the example data set whilst giving similar output:

```
> system.time(replicate(1000, zeroVar(dat)))
   user  system elapsed 
  3.334   0.000   3.335 
> system.time(replicate(1000, foo(dat)))
   user  system elapsed 
  0.324   0.000   0.324
```

Simon's solution here is similarly quick on this example:

```
> system.time(replicate(1000, which(!unlist(lapply(dat, 
+             function(x) 0 == var(if (is.factor(x)) as.integer(x) else x))))))
   user  system elapsed 
  0.392   0.000   0.395
```

but you'll have to see if they scale similarly to real problem sizes.

Comment: As I noted in my (weaker) solution, beware of `length(unique(x))` unless you're sure x is all integers.

Comment: A working solution seems actually `which(!unlist(lapply(dat, 
+             function(x) 0 == var(if (is.factor(x)) as.integer(x) else x))))` as the  current one refers precisely to the 0 variance columns.

Answer (score 29):

You may also want to look into the `nearZeroVar()` function in the caret package.

If you have one event out of 1000, it might be a good idea to discard these data (but this depends on the model). `nearZeroVar()` can do that.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I've actually been using `nearZeroVar()`, and this question is based on that function. I've occasionally found myself in the situation where I really only want to remove zero variance variables, and deal with the "near zero variance" variables in another way (for example by later combining several near zero variance variables into a new variable).

Comment: I just tried this methods, when you are using `nearZeroVar()`, set `saveMetrics = T`, then the output will give you both `zeroVar` (0 variance) and  `nzv` (near 0 variance), by setting other threshold in the function, you can decide the cutoff for the percentage of distinct values for near 0 variance. So, I think this method is simpler and flexible

Answer (score 11):

Simply don't use `table` - it's extremely slow on numeric vectors since it converts them to strings. I would probably use something like

```
var0 <- unlist(lapply(df, function(x) 0 == var(if (is.factor(x)) as.integer(x) else x)))
```

It will be `TRUE` for 0-variance, `NA` for columns with NAs and `FALSE` for non-zero variance

Comment: How hard would it be to make it `TRUE` for columns with all `NA`s and `FALSE` for columns with a mix of `NA`s and other values?

Comment: Nice. Is there any reason -- here or more generally -- to prefer `unlist(lapply(...))` to `sapply(...)`?

Comment: Well, `sapply` calls `lapply` and then works a bit more on the result, and finally calls `unlist` so I just like to use more primitive functions so I know what they do - that's just my personal preference (sometimes more efficient).

Comment: Easy - just pass through `na.rm` to `var` as you did with `table`: `var0 <- function(df, na.rm=FALSE) unlist(lapply(df, function(x) 0 == var(if (is.factor(x)) as.integer(x) else x, na.rm=na.rm)))`

Answer (score 7):

Use the `Caret` Package and the function `nearZeroVar`

```
require(caret)
NZV<- nearZeroVar(dataset, saveMetrics = TRUE)
NZV[NZV[,"zeroVar"] > 0, ] 
NZV[NZV[,"zeroVar"] + NZV[,"nzv"] > 0, ]
```

Answer (score 3):

Because I'm an idiot who keeps googling the same question, let me leave a `tidyverse` approach that I've settled on:

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- df %>%
  select(
    - {
      df %>%
        map_dbl(~ length(table(.x, useNA = "ifany"))) %>%
        {which(. == 1)} %>%
        names()
    }
  )
```

I think this could be made shorter but I'm too tired!

Comment: How about `df %>% select(where(function(x) var(x) != 0))`

Answer (score 2):

Well, save yourself some coding time:

```
Rgames: foo
      [,1]  [,2] [,3]
 [1,]    1 1e+00    1
 [2,]    1 2e+00    1
 [3,]    1 3e+00    1
 [4,]    1 4e+00    1
 [5,]    1 5e+00    1
 [6,]    1 6e+00    2
 [7,]    1 7e+00    3
 [8,]    1 8e+00    1
 [9,]    1 9e+00    1
 [10,]    1 1e+01    1
Rgames: sd(foo)
[1] 0.000000e+00 3.027650e+00 6.749486e-01
Warning message:
sd(<matrix>) is deprecated.
 Use apply(*, 2, sd) instead.
```

To avoid nasty floating-point roundoffs, take that output vector, which I'll call "bar," and do something like `bar[bar< 2*.Machine$double.eps] <- 0` and then  finally your data frame `dat[,as.logical(bar)]` should do the trick.

Comment: Carl - try it with the posted data frame - you'll get `NA`s due to factors ;)

Comment: @Simon - yeah, I know... I skipped the steps to clean up and/or validate the source data.  I plead laziness.

Answer (score 2):

How about using `factor` to count the number of unique elements and looping with `sapply`:

```
dat[sapply(dat, function(x) length(levels(factor(x)))>1)]
   B  D F
1  3 10 I
2  4 10 J
3  6 10 I
4  9 10 J
5  2 10 I
6  9 10 J
7  9 10 I
8  7 10 J
9  6 10 I
10 1  1 J
```

NAs are excluded by default, but this can be changed with the `exclude` parameter of `factor`:

```
dat[sapply(dat, function(x) length(levels(factor(x,exclude=NULL)))>1)]
   B  D F  G
1  3 10 I 10
2  4 10 J 10
3  6 10 I 10
4  9 10 J 10
5  2 10 I 10
6  9 10 J 10
7  9 10 I 10
8  7 10 J 10
9  6 10 I 10
10 1  1 J NA
```

Answer (score 0):

I think having zero variance is equivalent to being constant and one can get around without doing any arithmetic operations at all. I would expect that range() outperforms var(), but I have not verified this:

```
removeConstantColumns <- function(a_dataframe, verbose=FALSE) {
  notConstant <- function(x) {
    if (is.factor(x)) x <- as.integer(x)
    return (0 != diff(range(x, na.rm=TRUE)))
  }
  bkeep <- sapply(a_dataframe, notConstant)
  if (verbose) {
    cat('removeConstantColumns: '
      , ifelse(all(bkeep)
        , 'nothing'
        , paste(names(a_dataframe)[!bkeep], collapse=',')
      , ' removed',  '\n')
  }
  return (a_dataframe[, bkeep])
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this custom function. I did not try it on data frames with 100+ variables.

```
remove_low_variance_cols <- function(df, threshold = 0) {
  n <- Sys.time() #See how long this takes to run
  remove_cols <- df %>%
    select_if(is.numeric) %>%
    map_dfr(var) %>%
    gather() %>% 
    filter(value <= threshold) %>%
    spread(key, value) %>%
    names()

  if(length(remove_cols)) {
    print("Removing the following columns: ")
    print(remove_cols)
  }else {
    print("There are no low variance columns with this threshold")
  }
  #How long did this script take?
  print(paste("Time Consumed: ", Sys.time() - n, "Secs."))
  return(df[, setdiff(names(df), remove_cols)])
}
```